# Twists of Hecke character

Tags: nt.number-theory

Let $\chi$ be a self-dual Hecke character over a CM field $E$ with root number $-1$. Then, how to show the existence of a finite order Hecke character $\eta$ over $E$ such that the twist $\chi\eta$ is self-dual with root number $1$? It seems that $\eta$ can even be chosen to be quadratic.